# Can I get numbers from @keyframes in CSS?

Tags: html, css

The below CSS animates a fade from one colour to another and back again.

```
@keyframes example {
    0%   {background-color:#cce0ff;}
    25%  {background-color:#66a3ff;}
    50%  {background-color:#cce0ff;}
    75%  {background-color:#66a3ff;}
    100% {background-color:#cce0ff;}
}
```

Assuming this works through cross-fading, is there any way of retrieving the numbers from the process?

For example: When at the 25% stage of the animation, can i take the float .25 and use it in another function?

I am trying to get the volume of a the music on my page to swell and fall as the colour fades in and out.

Comment: Not that I'm aware. You could use the # to populate something via the `content` property, and either show that on the page or use it with javascript or something to do whatever else you want to do with it. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LWOOQV

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you can't 'extract' CSS properties as such, you can achieve the same result you're looking for, thanks to the magic of [**CSS variables**](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/css/a-guide-to-using-css-variables.html)! Essentially, you can set a variable that will hold the same value for use in both declarations.

First, you need to set the variables to be used inside both declarations:

```
:root {
--one: 0%;
--two: 25%;
--three: 50%;
--four: 75%;
--five: 100%;
}
```

Then simply reference these variables in the declarations you wish to use them in as such:

```
@keyframes example {
  var(--one)   {background-color:#cce0ff;}
  var(--two)   {background-color:#66a3ff;}
  var(--three) {background-color:#cce0ff;}
  var(--four)  {background-color:#66a3ff;}
  var(--five)  {background-color:#cce0ff;}
}

[Another Declaration] {
  volume: var(--two);
}
```

This will set the volume to 25% in the second declaration, while also setting a background colour of `#66a3ff` at a 25% keyframe.

Hope this helps! :)